# Jquery recursive function... then, alert

Tags: function, recursion, callback

I have a recursive function with an "if/else" condition.
I would like an "alert" window to open when the condition IS COMPLETE,
but the "alert" window opens BEFORE the condition ends. Why ?

```js
function myFunc(num) {

  newNum = num + 1;

  if (newNum < 10000) {
    $('body').append(newNum + ', ');
    myFunc(newNum);
  } else {
    alert("...finished !")
  }
}

myFunc(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It may be semantics, but I'm going to disagree with your assertion - the alert does display when the *condition* is complete.  The browser doesn't update the display until after the function ends.

Comment: Someone modified my statement: we put "1000" for my variable, whereas I had put 10000! ... with 10000, we can see the "alert" window that appears while the request doesn’t is not over yet ...

Comment: Works the same for me (Chrome) whether it's 1, 100, 1000 or 10000 - it builds the html (no output changes), shows the alert, then renders the output.  Are you seeing *some* output before the alert?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 49. On Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will only render changes instigated by the Javascript once the Javascript has finished executing its synchronous code and resources are free. You can alert after a `setTimeout` instead:

```js
function myFunc(num) {

  newNum = num + 1;

  if (newNum < 10000) {
    $('body').append(newNum + ', ');
    myFunc(newNum);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => alert("...finished !"), 200);
  }
}

myFunc(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, if you want the alert to occur as soon as possible without using a magic number like 200, you can queue a `setAnimationFrame` callback (which will run just before the browser repaints), call `setTimeout` in that callback, so that the `setTimeout` runs immediately after repaint occurs:

```js
function myFunc(num) {

  newNum = num + 1;

  if (newNum < 10000) {
    $('body').append(newNum + ', ');
    myFunc(newNum);
  } else {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      setTimeout(() => alert("...finished !"));
    });
  }
}

myFunc(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi. This is your second solution that interests me, because in fact, it is not an 'alert' window that I want to open, but I would like to execute a second function! ... A kind of 'callback' that would be triggered once the first function is completed ... Thank you for your response. This will help me move forward.

Comment: Done...:-) ... Thanks.